# how to drag a UIButton Scrollview to UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

i want to drag a button `UIScrollView` to another UIView using `UIPanGesture`. These both views are child of Xib View. I have already tried to create a copy of `UIButtonView` but i m not able to move this smoothly.

**Here is some code which i am implementing:**

```
-(void) PanGestureFunc :(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{
     CGRect originOnScreen = [recognizer.view convertRect:self.view.bounds toView:nil];





     if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
       {

           if([[recognizer.view superview].subviews containsObject:recognizer.view])
             {
                 btn = (UIButton *)recognizer.view;
                 btn.tag = [recognizer.view tag];

                 [recognizer.view removeFromSuperview];
                 [self.view addSubview:btn];

                  float pointX = originOnScreen.origin.x + btn.frame.size.width/2;
                  float pointY = originOnScreen.origin.y + btn.frame.size.height/2;

                 [btn setCenter:CGPointMake(pointX, pointY)];
              }


             CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
             btn.center = CGPointMake(btn.center.x + translation.x,
                             btn.center.y + translation.y);

            [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];


        }



}
```

Please solve this as soon as possible..

Comment: You want to drag a `UIButton ScrollView`? What on earth is that? `UIButton` and `UIScrollView` are two entirely different controls.

Comment: Anyways. Just remove the button from scrollview and add it as subview to your destination UIView. Or if your question is how to make a smooth animation for this process, edit your question to exactly state that in title.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

In `Viewdidload`

```
  UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 30);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];


[self.view addSubview:button];
```

And action method is like,

```
 - (IBAction) imageMoved:(id) sender withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
UIControl *control = sender;

UITouch *t = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint pPrev = [t previousLocationInView:control];
CGPoint p = [t locationInView:control];

CGPoint center = control.center;
center.x += p.x - pPrev.x;
center.y += p.y - pPrev.y;
control.center = center;
}
```

Hope this will help :)